# Как сделать постоянно бегущую строку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

есть блок

```css
.history-content__marquee {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3.375rem;
  line-height: 4.375rem;
}

.node-marquee {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100px;
  &__el {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="history-content__marquee">
  <div class="marquee node-marquee">
    <div class="node-marquee__el">девяностые 90-е —</div>
    <div class="node-marquee__el">&nbsp;девяностые 90-е —</div>
    <div class="node-marquee__el">&nbsp;девяностые 90-е —</div>
    <div class="node-marquee__el">&nbsp;девяностые 90-е —</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

как сделать его постоянно бегущим как вот здесь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чем вам не нравится стандартный `<marquee>текст</marquee>` ? http://htmlbook.ru/html/marquee

Comment: при загрузке страницы, текст должен быть сразу на всю ширину о левого края до правого и без пробелов двигаться

Answer (score 1):

Есть плагин `jQuery.Marquee - <strong>duration</strong>` указывает время прокрутки, `<strong>stratVisible</strong>` делает так, чтобы линию сразу было полностью видно, а `<strong>duplicated</strong>`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.marquee').marquee({
    duration: 7000,
    startVisible: true,
    duplicated: true
  });
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  font-size: 3.375rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<div class='marquee' style='overflow:hidden'>девяностые 90-е — девяностые 90-е — девяностые 90-е —</div>
```

делает текст бесконечным.